# Blurred lockscreen, can't find it

Tags: lock-screens, wallpaper

I had Resurrection Remix 6.0.1 on my Nexus 6p. I can't remember how it happened, but at some point my lock screen background became transparent-ish/blurred, so what I saw was whatever was open on my phone right before I locked it, but a little blurred. I really like that. But later I flashed RR 7.1.1, and now I have no idea where that is. Any help?

Comment: I think blurred lock screen is only available in cm13, and not in cm 14.1

Comment: @RahulGopi So They took it out in Nougat? I'm using Resurrection Remix, not CyanogenMod.